# Google Apps SOAP Request seems to send GET Request instead of POST

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a simple SOAP request that I know works through testing through SOAPUI, but it seems the Google Apps Script below is ignoring the method POST and sending as a get because the response comes back with GET of the WSDL page.

```
var webservice = 'https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01/contactmanagement.asmx?WSDL';
//Various XML parsing.  
var xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01">'
+'   <soap:Header/>'
+'   <soap:Body>'
+'      <ns:ImmediateUpload>'
+'         <!--Optional:-->'
+'        <ns:authentication>'
+'            <!--Optional:-->'
+'            <ns:Username>user</ns:Username>'
+'            <!--Optional:-->'
+'            <ns:Password>pass</ns:Password>'
+'         </ns:authentication>'
+'         <ns:UpdateExistingContacts>true</ns:UpdateExistingContacts>'
+'         <ns:TriggerWorkflow>false</ns:TriggerWorkflow>'
+'         <!--Optional:-->'
+'         <ns:contacts>'
+'            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'            <ns:ContactData>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:ContactKey>'
+'                  <!--<ns:ContactId>?</ns:ContactId>-->'
+'                  <!--Optional:-->'
+'                  <ns:ContactUniquedentifier>email</ns:ContactUniqueIdentifier>'
+'               </ns:ContactKey>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:EmailAddress IsNull="false">email</ns:EmailAddress>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:FirstName IsNull="true"></ns:FirstName>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:LastName IsNull="true"></ns:LastName>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:PhoneNumber IsNull="true"></ns:PhoneNumber>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:Fax IsNull="true"></ns:Fax>'
+'               <ns:Status>Subscribed</ns:Status>'
+'               <ns:MailFormat>Both</ns:MailFormat>'
+'               <ns:IsTestContact>false</ns:IsTestContact>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:CustomAttributes>'
+'                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'                  <ns:CustomAttribute Id="9553008" IsNull="false">08/19/2020 4:00 PM</ns:CustomAttribute>'
+'               </ns:CustomAttributes>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:AddToGroup>'
+'                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'                  <!--<ns:int>?</ns:int>-->'
+'               </ns:AddToGroup>'
+'               <!--Optional:-->'
+'               <ns:RemoveFromGroup>'
+'                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'                  <!--<ns:int>?</ns:int>-->'
+'               </ns:RemoveFromGroup>'
+'            </ns:ContactData>'
+'         </ns:contacts>'
+'         <!--Optional:-->'
+'         <ns:globalAddToGroup>'
+'            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'            <!--<ns:int>?</ns:int>-->'
+'         </ns:globalAddToGroup>'
+'         <!--Optional:-->'
+'         <ns:globalRemoveFromGroup>'
+'            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->'
+'            <!--<ns:int>?</ns:int>-->'
+'         </ns:globalRemoveFromGroup>'
+'      </ns:ImmediateUpload>'
+'   </soap:Body>'
+'</soap:Envelope>';

var options = {   
  headers:{
       method : 'post',
       payload  : xml,
       contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
      'SOAPAction' : '"https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01/ImmediateUpload"',
       muteHttpExceptions : true
  },

};  


//UrlFetchApp is a powerful built-in library from Google  

var serviceaddress =  webservice ;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceaddress, options);
```

I'm new to using Google Apps Scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options object is not formatted correctly. It should read as:

```js
var options = {
    method:"POST",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    headers:{
        "SOAPAction": "https://ws.campaigner.com/2013/01/ImmediateUpload"
    },
    payload:xml
};
```

Comment: That did it. Wow, you have no idea how silly I feel. I figured it was something small like this. I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: In case anyone else is banging their head off the wall.....
`Logger.log("result: ", result.getResponseCode()) ` <== DOESN'T WORK
`console.log("result: ", result.getContentText())` <== WORKS